# How to use values of local variables in inherited functions of java?

Tags: java, inheritance, extends

I have 2 classes A and B such that

```
public class A {
    public String a = "hey";

    public void printA() {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
```

and

```
public class B extends A{
    public String a = "Jude";
}
```

What do I need to do so that the output of the lines below is `Jude`

```
B object = new B();
object.printA();    //This should output Jude
```

Comment: Even if you were to `extends A` the string would not be overwritten.

Comment: You cannot override fields; you can only override methods

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access the subclass field from the superclass. However you can change it in subclass like this:

```
public class B extends A {
    B() {
        this.a = "Jude";
    }
}
```

This way you don't declare the new field, but change the value of existing one. Note that `extends A` is necessary to specify that `B` is subclass of `A`.

Alternatively you may consider using a method instead of field:

```
public class A {
    public String getA() {
        return "hey";
    }

    public void printA() {
        System.out.println(getA());
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    @Override
    public String getA() {
        return "Jude";
    }
}
```

Note that in Java "variable" term usually applied to local variables declared within methods. You are speaking about "field", not "variable".

Answer (score 0):

Just change your declaration of a to this.a like so.

```
public class B extends A{
    B(){
        super();
        //Could hardcode this.a to "Jude" here if you want.
    }

    B(String word){
        super();
        this.a = word;
    }
}
```

a is already defined for B from the superclass A so you need to use "this" to access it.

You can use it like so

```
B object = new B("Jude");
object.printA(); //"Jude"
```

Comment: better to have `A(String)`, so that B can do `super("Jude")`

Comment: @bayou.io I like that better too. I implemented it on B instead

Answer (score 0):

Fields can not be overridden. Methods can; use methods instead:

```
public class A {
    public String getA() {
        return "hey";
    }
    public void printA() {
        System.out.println(getA());
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    public String getA() {
        return "Jude";
    }
}
```

That's all. If `getA()` is not called outside these classes, cincdider making it `protected`.

Answer (score -2):

The Java® Language Specification, Java SE 8 Edition

> If the class declares a field with a certain name, then the
>   declaration of that field is said to hide any and all accessible
>   declarations of fields with the same name in superclasses, and
>   superinterfaces of the class.

Not sure If I need to further explain it for the audience, but YOU CANNOT "use values of local variables in inherited functions of java", why? See above.

Comment: An easy alternative is to not redefine it in the subclass but just rewrite the superclass variable from the subclass. See my answer below.